# Issue installing OpenCV 4.1.2 on Jetson Nano. import cv2, No module named 'cv2'

Tags: nvidia, opencv, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano, python

I installed OpenCV 4.1.2 from source with CUDA support. Had no issues. and created a symbolic link from OpenCV’s installation directory to my virtualenv

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python3.6/cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so cv2.so
```

I am having an issue with import cv2

```
$ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
>>>
```

I checked site-packages directory and I can see cv2.so. I am obviously missing something.
The main issue here in my view I am not able to link to my virtualenv, in fact I am able to check my installation and its working

```
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6$ python
Python 3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved a very very little mistake
I changed the name from

```
cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so to cv2.so
```

I realized it was an issue with one of the folders, this will do the magic:

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/python-3.6/cv2.so cv2.so
```

notice its python-3.6 not python3.6 after cv2